# Show pictures on Plot in R using for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-science

I have some images, I want to add those images on plot by defining coordinates.

to add single image on plot, I have this code.

```
require(jpeg)
img<-readJPEG("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/0.jpg")
#now open a plot window with coordinates
plot(1:10,ty="n")
#specify the position of the image through bottom-left and top-right coords
rasterImage(img,2,2,4,4)
```

But I want show multiple images in R plot

like this

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the code below will show a way how to do what the question asks for. It is not a full solution, since the actual use case graph coordinates will not be the same.

The obvious trick is to shift the picture

- **vertically**  by changing only the `y` coordinates. Add the same amount to both `ybottom` and `ytop` to keep the proportions.
- **horizontally** by changing only the `x` coordinates. Add the same amount to both `xleft` and `xright` to keep the proportions.

In the case of the figure, the amount added was `3`.

```
library(jpeg)

img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))

old_par <- par(mar = c(2, 3, 1, 1) + 0.1)

xleft <- 2
ybottom <- 21
xright <- 6
ytop <- 25

plot(seq(0, 60, length.out = 31), 0:30, type = "n")
for(i in 1:17){
  xleft <- xleft + 3
  xright <- xright + 3
  rasterImage(img, xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop)
}
for(i in 1:5){
  ybottom <- ybottom - 3
  ytop <- ytop - 3
  rasterImage(img, xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop)
}
for(i in 1:16){
  xleft <- xleft - 3
  xright <- xright - 3
  rasterImage(img, xleft, ybottom, xright, ytop)
}

par(old_par)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rui Barradas for your prompt help, Instead of headcoding x and y values, can we analyze the pattern and build a logic, like if x is increasing and Y in constant(means flow is in +ve horizontal direction then keep adding xleft values).